# How do I make an array of 2D arrays that are not all the same width?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, arduino

This works, I know.

```
int8_t intArray7[][2] = {-2, -1,
                          0, 1,
                          2, 3,
                          4, 5,
                          6, 7};

int8_t intArray8[][2] = {10, 9,
                          8, 7,
                          6, 5,
                          4, 3,
                          2, 1, 
                          0, -1,
                         -2, -3};

int8_t intArray9[][2] = {100, 101,
                         102, 103};

int8_t (*arrayOf2DArrays[])[2] = {intArray7, intArray8, intArray9};
```

Now, what if the 2D arrays are not all the same width? How do I make that work?

Ex: this does NOT work, since intArray11 is width 3:

```
 int8_t intArray10[][2] = {-2, -1,
                            0, 1,
                            2, 3,
                            4, 5,
                            6, 7};

int8_t intArray11[][3] = {10, 9, 8,
                           7, 6, 5, 
                           4, 3, 2,
                           1, 0, -1};

int8_t intArray12[][2] = {100, 101,
                          102, 103};

int8_t (*arrayOf2DArrays2[])[] = {intArray10, intArray11, intArray12};
```

What must one do to make an array of arrays of different element sizes?

I plan on keeping track of each of the array sizes using separate variables.

Comment: check which array is the biggest then manipulate the rest to add 0's to make the rows match the add them all together.

Comment: I'd bet you'll need some more braces. Get some from my side `{{ x, y }, { z, 43 }}`. Well, seriously: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int8_t>>`.

Comment: `What must one do to make an array of arrays of different element sizes?` in C++ .. you could use an [STL container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Comment: In C++ the bounds of the array are not part of the array data itself.  It's elsewhere (e.g., in the type, or in some variable you maintain yourself).  So, where are you going to put the information on the size of each array that is an element of your top-level array?  When you answer that you'll begin to see how to structure your arrays by wrapping a class around the whole thing, or around each element-array, or both.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I was just reading about STL vectors today, so your answer makes perfect sense. However, this will be running on an 8-bit ATTiny microcontroller with 512 bytes RAM and ~3kB available flash memory space. I haven't tried using the STL vector class on one of these, but I imagine it takes up a little extra memory I can't spare.

Comment: @GabrielStaples If you want to have certain sizes and to allocate on the stack you may consider using `std::array<>`instead.

Comment: Your best bet (if I am reading your comments above correctly) is to use an array of int pointers and then allocate the memory width to each indexed pointer to match the need. Although you may find that handling the memory management yourself may not be worth any marginal performance gain. The STL container will undoubtedly do a better job at memory management in most cases than you would. If the containers management is not to your liking, you could always create a custom allocator.

Comment: @GabrielStaples - w.r.t. 512 bytes RAM limitation: You're right, `std::vector` will not be good for you since it'll do heap allocation with overhead.  You'll need to "roll" your own data structure, probably with naked pointers.  That is - don't type your top-level array as a 2D array - type it as a vector of `int8_t**`.  `operator []` will still work to index 1-dimensionally for each pointer.  You can write an `operator [,,]`, if you want, that returns an element of one of the arrays (by referring to your separate array of array sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most compatible method is to use a `struct` (or `class`) to describe the array:

```
struct Array_Attributes
{
  int8_t * array_memory;
  unsigned int maximum_rows;
  unsigned int maximum_columns;
};
```

You can treat the `array_memory` as a multidimensional array by converting from 2d to 1d indices:

```
unsigned index = row * maximum_columns + column;
```

You could also make an array out of linked lists.  This would allow dimensions of different sizes.

```
+-------+     +----------+     +----------+  
| row 0 | --> | column 0 | --> | column 1 | ...  
+-------+     +----------+     +----------+  
    |  
    |
    V  
+-------+     +----------+     +----------+  
| row 1 | --> | column 0 | --> | column 1 | ...  
+-------+     +----------+     +----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Kindly stop and visualize, for a moment,"* what "the *memory"* actually looks like . . .

`arrayOf2DArrays2`, apparently, consists of: "an array of three *pointers."*

Unfortunately-for-you, there is *nothing,* in any of this, to predict what each of these three elements *consist of,* and we can very-plainly see that all three of them are different.  **"But, *C++* ... *cannot!"*** (Because: you have so-far provided no means for it to do so.)

Therefore, you now need to avail yourself of C++'s *"container classes."*

`arrayOf2DArrays2`*ought* to consist of "a container," presently containing (three) other *"containers,"* each one of which is capable of telling you how many elements *it* contains, and also of throwing a runtime-exception should you attempt to access an element that *it* does not contain.

When you have done this, a "simple" statement such as `arrayOf2DArrays2[x][y]` *(or what-have-you ...)* will "automagically" be understood by C++ to refer to an actually-complex series of events: *first,* the outer-container will be asked to resolve `[x]`, *then* the thus-referenced inner-container will be asked to resolve `[y]`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'd like to answer my own question too. There are many good ideas here, but let me post this simple and low-memory-cost solution. For devices of minimal memory (ex: an ATTiny AVR microcontroller with 512 bytes of RAM and a few kB program flash memory), I think this may be the best solution. I've tested it; it works. Use an array of pointers to int8_t's--ie: an array of pointers to 1D arrays, as follows:

```
int8_t intArray10[][2] = {-2, -1,
                            0, 1,
                            2, 3,
                            4, 5,
                            6, 7};

int8_t intArray11[][3] = {10, 9, 8,
                           7, 6, 5, 
                           4, 3, 2,
                           1, 0, -1};

int8_t intArray12[][2] = {100, 101,
                          102, 103};

//get some array specs we need about the arrays
byte arrayLengths[] = {sizeof(intArray10)/sizeof(int8_t), sizeof(intArray11)/sizeof(int8_t), 
                        sizeof(intArray12)/sizeof(int8_t)}; //redundant division since int8_t is 1 byte, but I want to leave it for verboseness and extension to other types 
byte arrayCols[] = {2, 3, 2};

//make pointers to int8_t's and point each pointer to the first element of each 2D array, as though each 2D array was a 1D array
//-this works because the arrays use contiguous memory 
int8_t *intArray10_p = &(intArray10[0][0]); 
int8_t *intArray11_p = &(intArray11[0][0]);
int8_t *intArray12_p = &(intArray12[0][0]);

//make an array of those pointers to 1D arrays 
int8_t *intArrayOfnDimArray[] = {intArray10_p, intArray11_p, intArray12_p};

//print the 3 arrays via pointers to (contiguous) 1D arrays:
//-Note: this concept and technique should work with ANY contiguous array of ANY number of dimensions
for (byte i=0; i<sizeof(intArrayOfnDimArray)/sizeof(intArrayOfnDimArray[0]); i++) //for each 2D array 
{
  for (byte j=0; j<arrayLengths[i]; j++) //for all elements of each 2D array 
  {
    Serial.print(intArrayOfnDimArray[i][j]); Serial.print("/"); //now read out the 2D array values (which are contiguous in memory) one at a time; STANDARD ARRAY ACCESS TECHNIQUE 
    Serial.print(*(intArrayOfnDimArray[i] + j)); Serial.print("/"); //ARRAY/POINTER TECHNIQUE (extra teaching moment)
    Serial.print((*(intArrayOfnDimArray + i))[j]); Serial.print("/"); //POINTER/ARRAY TECHNIQUE
    Serial.print(*(*(intArrayOfnDimArray + i) + j)); //POINTER/POINTER TECHNIQUE 

    //add a comma after every element except the last one on each row, to present it in 2D array form 
    static byte colCount = 0; //initialize as being on "Column 1" (0-indexed)
    if (colCount != arrayCols[i]-1) //if not on the last column number 
      Serial.print(", ");
    else //colCount==arrayCols[i]-1 //if we *are* on the last column number 
      Serial.println();
    colCount++;
    if (colCount==arrayCols[i])
      colCount = 0; //reset 
  }
  Serial.println(F("-----")); //spacer 
}
```

Output:

```
-2/-2/-2/-2, -1/-1/-1/-1
0/0/0/0, 1/1/1/1
2/2/2/2, 3/3/3/3
4/4/4/4, 5/5/5/5
6/6/6/6, 7/7/7/7
-----
10/10/10/10, 9/9/9/9, 8/8/8/8
7/7/7/7, 6/6/6/6, 5/5/5/5
4/4/4/4, 3/3/3/3, 2/2/2/2
1/1/1/1, 0/0/0/0, -1/-1/-1/-1
-----
100/100/100/100, 101/101/101/101
102/102/102/102, 103/103/103/103
-----
```

Note: as Thomas Matthews teaches in his answer, to access a specific 2D array, row, and column, use the following:

```
byte index = row * maximum_columns + column;
```

which in my above example would be:

```
byte rowColIndex = desiredRow * arrayCols[desired2DArrayIndex] + desiredColumn;
int8_t val = intArrayOfnDimArray[desired2DArrayIndex][rowColIndex];
```

Note: `byte` is equivalent to `uint8_t`.